# NativeView catches Exception: TypeError after returning back to the app

Tags: nativescript

I have a function inside my **Component_1** :

```
methods: {

    interactBoxToggel () {

        let page = this.$refs.Home.nativeView;
        let interactBox = page.getViewById( 'interactBox' );

        console.log( interactBox );

    }

} , 

mounted () {
    bus.$on( 'interactBoxToggel' , this.interactBoxToggel )
}
```

It **always** work if it triggered from inside **Component_1**,

Now I port it to the **Component_2**:

```
methods: {

    buttonCotrol( buttonName ) {

        bus.$emit( 'interactBoxToggel' );
        console.log(buttonName);

    }

}
```

It works too, but if I exit the app by "swipe to close" (*Android 9 Fullscreen Gesture*) and come back again to the app and call it from inside **Component_2**, I will get error:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onTouch failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeView' of undefined
System.err: 
...
```

Why this happens? How can I solve it?

Comment: It's the context, `this` will be pointing to your current page when you emit it from Component_2, therefore there will be no Home ref exists. Do not update previous page while you are in another page as that technically doesn't exists on UI. Push updates only on navigated events.

Comment: There is just one Page, Home page, (Home is Component_1) and it contains (Component_2) as well, and before closing the app the function works when it call from comonent_1 or component_2.

Comment: Please share a minimal Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.244317125.1916839120.1570865237-902785801.1570194662&template=play-vue&id=5Q8tXW

Comment: I want to manipulate that green Box, by tapping on icons you can see on the middle(they are inside component_2 [settings.vue] )

Comment: just close the app and reopen it without killing that, you will get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding event listener every time on `mounted` callback. When app is closed the component will be destroyed and mounted again on resume, so you will have 2 active listeners but only one will be valid for the session. As many times you close and open, you will have as many listeners added.

You must remove the listener when it's destroyed.

```
    destroyed() {
        bus.$off("interactBoxToggel", this.interactBoxToggel);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, in this case, is there any method that I can introduce interactBoxToggel()  instead of on mounted() , and so there will be no need to remove the Listener ? (I ask just out of curiosity)